# How to change the year of a date in a pandas dataframe given various conditions?

Tags: python, date

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
    ID  Date    
1   3   2016-04-01  
2   3   2016-04-02  
3   3   2016-04-03  
4   3   2016-04-04  
5   3   2016-04-05  
6   3   2017-04-01  
7   3   2017-04-02  
8   3   2017-04-03  
9   3   2017-04-04  
10  3   2017-04-05
11  7   2016-04-01  
12  7   2016-04-02  
13  7   2016-04-03  
14  7   2016-04-04  
15  7   2016-04-05  
16  7   2017-04-01  
17  7   2017-04-02  
18  7   2017-04-03  
19  7   2017-04-04  
20  7   2017-04-05
```

I want to change the year of the dates given two conditions. The conditions are the value of the ID and the year of the Date. For example, if ID = 3 and the year is 2016, I want to change it to 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
def f(x):
  if x['ID'] == 3 and '2016' in x['Date']:
    return x['Date'].replace('2014','2016')
else:
  return x['Date']

df['new_column'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Depending on how the date is stored you have to modify. This example is for a simple string, but should be adaptable to other types.

If you want to use a lambda function:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date'].replace('2014', '2016') if x['ID'] == 3 and '2016' in x['Date'] else x['Date'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, if your data is stored as a `datetime` object, your corresponding function is `x['date'] = x['date'].replace(2016)`, and your condition is `x['date'].year == 2014`

Following the previous answer, the one-liner would look like this:

```
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date'].replace(2014) if x['ID'] == 3 and x['date'].year == 2016 else x['date'], axis=1)`
```

Generally speaking, I'd recommend working with `datetime` for dates and times.

Answer (score 0):

```
data['Date'] = data.apply(lambda x: x['Date'].replace('2016','2014') if (x['ID'] == 3 and "2016" in x['Date']) else x['Date'], axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
    ID  Date
0   3   2014-04-01
1   3   2014-04-02
2   3   2014-04-03
3   3   2014-04-04
4   3   2014-04-05
5   3   2017-04-01
6   3   2017-04-02
7   3   2017-04-03
8   3   2017-04-04
9   3   2017-04-05
10  7   2016-04-01
11  7   2016-04-02
12  7   2016-04-03
13  7   2016-04-04
14  7   2016-04-05
15  7   2017-04-01
16  7   2017-04-02
17  7   2017-04-03
18  7   2017-04-04
19  7   2017-04-05
```